# Регулярки js

Tags: регулярные-выражения, match, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Есть строка:

```
var tpl = "<div>{title}</div> <div>{description}</div>";
```

и при помощи регулярки:

```
console.log(tpl.match(/\{[^\}]+\}/g));
```

я вытаскиваю из неё

```
["{title}", "{description}"]
```

а мне нужны сами названия переменных, то есть вот так:

```
["title", "description"]
```

Вопрос: можно ли это сделать непосредственно в регулярном выражении или же нужно писать функцию, коротая будет потом всё это обрезать?

Comment: Да, можно.

Comment: Если не знаешь, что делать, то делай то, что знаешь. По регуляркам вот хороший сайт для составления/тестирования https://regex101.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@Станислав Далинин](/users/6975/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD)

1. Открываем http://javascript.ru/RegExp
2. http://javascript.ru/regexp/exec

---

```
var tpl = "<div>{title}</div> <div>{description}</div>",
    regexp = /\{([^\}]+)\}/g, matches,
    results  = [];

while (matches = regexp.exec(tpl)) {
    results.push(matches[1]);
}
console.log(results);
```

---

```
var tpl = "<div>{title}</div> <div>{description}</div>";
var results = (tpl.match(/\{[^\}]+\}/g) || []).map(function (value) {
   return value.slice(1, -1) 
});
console.log(results);
```

---

```
var tpl = "<div>{title}</div> <div>{description}</div>";
var results = [];
tpl.replace(/\{([^\}]+)\}/g, function (_, value) {
    results.push(value);
});
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\{([^\}]+)\}
```

Comment: И? Если просто добавить группу, результат будет тот же самый.

Comment: А ты попробуй. Здесь не просто группа добавлена, а фигурные скобки вынесены за границы группы. Естественно, эту строку оберни в слеши / и не забудь g в конце поставить.

Comment: @RubaXa,  вот пример https://regex101.com/r/xD5aO4/1

Comment: Да пожалуйста:

    var tpl = "<div>{title}</div> <div>{description}</div>";
    tpl.match(/\{([^\}]+)\}/g); // ["{title}", "{description}"]